# Lenguaje C Memoria dinamica en funciones

Tags: c, funciones, punteros

Quiero reservar memoria para una variable dinamica y asignarle valor en una misma funcion para evitar duplicar codigo, pero no puedo hacer que el valor lo tome en el main, solo queda en la funcion. MNuchas gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void creadin(int *);

int main() {

    int *a,*b,*c;
    creadin(a); //no pongo ampersand porque al ser puntero ya es una direccion de memoria por lo cual deberia ser modificada

    creadin(b);
    creadin(c);
    return 0;
}

void creadin(int *a){

  a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

  scanf("%d", &(*a));

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //no pongo ampersand porque al ser puntero ya es una direccion de memoria por lo cual deberia ser modificada

Incorrecto. Si quieres modificar cualquier cosa externa a tu función **que no sea de alcance global**, tienes que usar un puntero**.

```
...
creadin(&a);

Void creadin(int **a){
  *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  scanf("%d", *a);
}
```